# JToolbarHelper not found error - advice on which file to fix it?

Tags: joomla-3.x

This isnt a request for a fix as I have done some research and found that I can add the code below and it should resolve the problem:

```
if(!class_exists('JToolbarHelper')) {
   require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/includes/toolbar.php';
}
```

This issue is, in which file do I need to put the code? The exact error is:

> Fatal error: Class 'JToolbarHelper' not found in
>   /home/waterfro/public_html/new/administrator/components/com_iproperty/helpers/iproperty.php on line 116

Ok updated - my bad, I have 2 joomla installations on the server - Line 116 of the code is the first brace in the following:

```
class IpToolbar extends JToolbarHelper
{
    public static function approveList($task = 'approve', $alt = 'COM_IPROPERTY_APPROVE')
    {
        $bar = JToolbar::getInstance('toolbar');
        $bar->appendButton('Standard', 'thumbs-up', $alt, $task, true);
    } 

    public static function unapproveList($task = 'unapprove', $alt = 'COM_IPROPERTY_UNAPPROVE')
    {
        $bar = JToolbar::getInstance('toolbar');
        $bar->appendButton('Standard', 'thumbs-down muted', $alt, $task, true);
    }

    public static function featureList($task = 'feature', $alt = 'COM_IPROPERTY_FEATURE')
    {
        $bar = JToolbar::getInstance('toolbar');
        $bar->appendButton('Standard', 'star', $alt, $task, true);
    } 

    public static function unfeatureList($task = 'unfeature', $alt = 'COM_IPROPERTY_UNFEATURE')
    {
        $bar = JToolbar::getInstance('toolbar');
        $bar->appendButton('Standard', 'star-empty', $alt, $task, true);
    }

    public static function superList($task = 'super', $alt = 'COM_IPROPERTY_SUPER')
    {
        $bar = JToolbar::getInstance('toolbar');
        $bar->appendButton('Standard', 'plus', $alt, $task, true);
    } 

    public static function unsuperList($task = 'unsuper', $alt = 'COM_IPROPERTY_UNSUPER')
    {
        $bar = JToolbar::getInstance('toolbar');
        $bar->appendButton('Standard', 'minus', $alt, $task, true);
    }

    public static function clearHits($msg = '', $task = 'clearhits', $alt = 'COM_IPROPERTY_CLEAR_HITS')
    {
        $bar = JToolbar::getInstance('toolbar');

        if ($msg)
        {
            $bar->appendButton('Confirm', $msg, 'refresh', $alt, $task, true);
        }
        else
        {
            $bar->appendButton('Standard', 'refresh', $alt, $task, true);
        }
    }

    public static function saveCatList($task = 'saveCats', $alt = 'JTOOLBAR_APPLY', $check = false)
    {
        $bar = JToolbar::getInstance('toolbar');
        $bar->appendButton('Standard', 'publish', $alt, $task, $check);
    } 

    public static function backupBtn($task = 'backupDB', $alt = 'COM_IPROPERTY_BACKUP', $check = false)
    {
        $bar = JToolbar::getInstance('toolbar');
        $bar->appendButton('Standard', 'new', $alt, $task, $check);
    }

    public static function restoreBtn($task = 'restoreDB', $alt = 'COM_IPROPERTY_RESTORE', $check = false)
    {
        $bar = JToolbar::getInstance('toolbar');
        $bar->appendButton('Standard', 'new', $alt, $task, $check);
    }

    public static function backBtn($alt = 'JTOOLBAR_BACK', $href = 'javascript:history.back();')
    {
        $bar = JToolbar::getInstance('toolbar');
        $bar->appendButton('Link', 'arrow-left', $alt, $href);
    }

    public static function importBtn($task = 'import', $alt = 'COM_IPROPERTY_IMPORT', $check = false)
    {
        $bar = JToolbar::getInstance('toolbar');
        $bar->appendButton('Standard', 'new', $alt, $task, $check);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me try and locate the correct location to add the require? I'll happily provide some more information should it be needed. 
Thanks
D

Comment: `com_iproperty` is a 3rd party extension, so assuming you're using the latest version, I'd suggest contacting the developer regarding this bug.

Comment: Hi Lodder, the client's subscription has expired and they do not wish to update it at present. I have contacted IProperty but they are unwilling to help obviously - I was hoping there would be a way to rectify this myself.

Comment: Fair enough. And are you sure that the code you've provided is from the `administrator/components/com_iproperty` rather than `components/com_iproperty` directory?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely from the Admin section - I'll added the full content to the post.

Comment: Admin pages should have that file loaded by default.

Comment: Ok, was looking in the wrong file - please see updated code

Comment: I've tried writing a class that extends JToolbarHelper in a helper of a compoenent, and it works fine. 

Is this error being thrown in the admin, or is it thrown on the front end with a reference to a file in the admin?

Comment: Try adding the fix you have above the line 'class IpToolbar extends JToolbarHelper' and see what happens.  If this does fix it, be wary that it suggests a bigger issue.  Really third party component should always be patched, even if that means paying the subs.

Answer (score 1):

Note you should be using:

```
JLoader::register('JToolbarHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/includes/toolbar.php');
```

going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just added the code below at the top of the file and the page loads correctly :)

```
if(!class_exists('JToolbarHelper')) {
   require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/includes/toolbar.php';
}
```

Thanks for all you support as always.
Regards
D